# How to inject DI Services in a WPF ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I'm implementing a DI container in a .NET Core WPF app.

The below setup works fine, but I don't know how to inject an interface in any of my view model's constructor.

In the `MainWindow` I want to instantiate two or more pages with their respective dependencies (side menu item click). How do I get the dependency container in order to resolve those dependencies?

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        private readonly ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private IConfiguration _configuration { get; set; }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeConfiguration();

            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            _serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        private void InitializeConfiguration()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

            _configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IConfiguration>(s => _configuration);
            services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
            services.AddTransient<IDeliveryService, DeliveryService>();

            services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
        }

        private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainWindow = _serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What view models?

Comment: @Nkosi I am trying to follow the MVVM pattern so I've structured the pages on Views, ViewModels and Models folders. At the moment, it is not as important since my only goal is to find a way to inject data in a class.

Comment: Have the view explicitly depend on the view model via constructor injection, register view model with container and the view model will be injected into the view when it is being resolved.

Comment: @Nkosi  In the MainWindow I want to instantiate 2 or more pages with their respective dependencies (side menu item click). How do I get the dependency container in order to resolve that dependency? do you have a code snippet in this regard? Can you please write an answer? Thanks!

Comment: You don't. You inject a factory or the view explicitly.

Comment: Plus the details in your last comment should have been in the original post to help other understand what it is you are trying to achieve.